# Как следует понимать Б.С.Мучника

Tags: грамотная-речь, редактура

Б.С. Мучник, один из основателей современной практической стилистики современного русского языка, автор трудов о методике исправления логико-коммуникативных ошибок, связанных с нарушением требований точности, ясности, логичности речи, (его пособие «Основы стилистики и редактирования» (Ростов н/Д, 1997), в частности, рекомендуется  для обязательного  изучения учителями и школьниками в "Методических материалах для председателей и членов предметных комиссий субъектов Российской Федерации по проверке выполнения заданий с развернутым ответом экзаменационных работ ЕГЭ  по русскому языку"), утверждает:«Следует говорить не о точности словоупотребления, а о точности выражения мысли, или о коммуникативной точности речи, которая может быть достигнута и при употреблении слова в ненормативном значении». Как следует понимать это утверждение? Справедливо ли оно?

Answer (score 4):

> Как следует понимать это утверждение?

Читать это утверждение надо в контексте с ранее произнесённым Мучником. Тогда всё становится понятным.

> В. Луговской разбирает пример из Гоголя: *«Вспомнил, вспомнил!» -
>   закричал он в страшном весельи и, размахнувши топор, пустил им со всей
>   силой в старуху. Топор на два вершка **вбежал** в дубовую дверь».*
>   Послушайте, как слово *вбежал* определяет страшную силу удара;
>   казалось бы, странное слово для топора, а какую динамичность придает
>   оно всей фразе».
>
> Нельзя, значит, считать, что использование слова в строгом
>   соответствии с его общенародным значением является «законом
>   словоупотребления». Особую силу и убедительность нередко получает как
>   раз то слово, которое употреблено в ненормативном, «сдвинутом»
>   значении (*«топор вбежал в дверь»*). Коммуникативная точность - это
>   полное соответствие сегмента речи именно мысли автора,а не
>   нормативному, зафиксированному в словарях значению слова.
>
> Термин «точное словоупотребление» (и всю стоящую за ним концепцию: точность =  «соответствие нормам словоупотребления») приходится, с
>   учетом всей речевой практики, в том числе практики художественной
>   литературы, признать недостаточно точным. **Следует говорить не о
>   точности словоупотребления, а о точном выражении мысли, или о
>   коммуникативной точности речи, которая может быть достигнута и при
>   употреблении слова в ненормативном значении**.

Comment: Все это, конечно, так. Я не сомневался, что источник найдут, и ход рассуждений Б.С. Мучника будет восстановлен. Вопрос в другом: проходит ли вообще по «ведомству» точности речи приведенный ученым пример?. Речь тут должна идти о выразительности и образности, которые автор теории письменной коммуникации не считает обязательными характеристиками стиля. Само же понятие индивидуального стиля он выводит вообще за пределы практической стилистики.  Нет ли  в приведенных умозаключениях Мучника определенной непоследовательности и скрытой подмены понятий?